# Trivial ways to improve application performance

Tags: c++, performance

Basically I am interested to know how far you go, to ensure your users get the best application.

1. Which one to prefer dynamic/static memory allocation, when both are possible.
2. Scraping `int` and using `short` or `int8_t`. Will it really help? Or it would be more of a headache?
3. Allocating a "proportionally" large amount of memory dynamically (due to lack of info on actual memory required). And then reallocating it to smaller memory (compact) and deleting the former. Eg. I allocate 1000 units of memory. Then after calculating, I determine that only 400 units are required. So I allocate new 400 units, copy the 400 items and then delete 1000 units. In this process i end up allocating even more memory i.e 1400 units at some time. So should I actually take pains to allocate new 400 units and let 600 units waste? **[main question]**
4. Any effective use of `union` to help lower memory usage?

I am sure there are more important points missing. Any other known or indigenous way to increase memory and time performance are welcome.

Comment: if they're trivial then they're not important, right?

Comment: 7: No; please read a good book, and start writing something that works and get a code review rather than worrying prematurely about things you heard in the pub.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a list question, or 7 questions in one. Either way, it doesn't seem like a good fit here.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I have already written around 2000 LOC and the application works partially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2. Static.  Don't allocate memory when you don't need to.`

`3. If the system is a 32-bit system, then the actual instructions to the processor will actually prefer uint32_t or int32_t...`

`5. If I need a generic data type that would need to be allocated several times in a loop, then a union can come in handy... to avoid allocating memory.`

`6. From my experience, allocating memory can be a slow process if it is done in a loop... You will see a performance increase if you allocate all the memory ahead of time, and then use it from a pool.  When the system has go find huge blocks of memory, it can be a bottleneck.`

`7. In real-time situations with large chunks of memory... yes... otherwise... eh... not really`

Hope this helps...  If you follow this style, you will notice improved performance.

Answer (score 9):

> 7 . Are my concerns real?

No. All the things you mentioned are generally useless micro-optimisations, especially with modern compilers. Write the code that is most *readable*, because code is read many more times than it is written.

Comment: Best answer I've ever read since I became a member of stackoverflow... :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming my fear!

Comment: You're welcome, I guess. What exactly *was* your fear?

Comment: Of getting flamed! Ha ha no really that my concerns are really not real, and i should stop thinking hard before writing any new piece of code!

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be much better suited for Programmers.StackExchange.com. Regardless, I usually follow the unix philosophy of don't fix a bottle neck until you see one.

As to your main question. That will use more processing cycles than just allocating the large block of memory and being done with it, so in that sense that is less efficient. Anyways, memory is fairly expendable these days and efficiency, re-usability, and readability are usually my main concerns.

If you are that concerned, pass -O3 to your compiler.